# Pandas to fill the color to the column header or Entire dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, css-selectors

I am trying to understand how to fill the color specific to dataframe column header or to the entire dataframe background.

I've just started and google around but did not get understanding to to it, there are good links such as [related link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57805803/how-to-to-add-background-color-to-a-specific-column-of-pandas-dataframe-and-save/57806265#57806265)  and  [another Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52110530/bold-column-in-pandas-dataframe-to-html) .

### Datatframe Below..

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({ 'Name':['James', 'Ricardo', 'Arie', 'Ruben', 'Naveen', 'Audery'], 'Sir Name':['Pullman', 'Jacob', 'Tilman', 'Juneja', 'Therry', 'Cuenin'], 'Country':['Holland', 'Holland', 'Holland', 'Holland', 'Holland', 'Holland'], 'Age':[38,28,27,29,26,27] })

>>> df
      Name Sir Name  Country  Age
0    James  Pullman  Holland   38
1  Ricardo    Jacob  Holland   28
2     Arie   Tilman  Holland   27
3    Ruben   Juneja  Holland   29
4   Naveen   Therry  Holland   26
5   Audery   Cuenin  Holland   27
```

Expected:

[image]

OR

Fill the color to the whole background

[image]

I have tried as follows but did not get the result.

```
>>> ss = df.style.set_table_styles([{ 'selector': 'th', 'props': [('background-color', 'black'), ('color', 'cyan')]}])
>>> print(ss)
<pandas.io.formats.style.Styler object at 0x7f5eccfedac8>
```

Comment: Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50664839/format-excel-column-header-for-better-visibility-and-color) thread.

Comment: Thanks @Erfan, but that links seems in particular to Excelwriter not to Pandas as dataframe header, may be i am not able to get that.

Comment: When you're reading in excel, pandas uses excelwriter under the hood, you can use that engine to edit pandas dataframe headers

Comment: but i'm not reading from the Excel.

Comment: Is there a way to Fill the bgcolor while doing `df.to_html` on the Linux console as i am not using the Jupitor not book.

Answer (score 1):

Style create html, [from the doc](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.io.formats.style.Styler.html#pandas.io.formats.style.Styler):

> If using in the Jupyter notebook, Styler has defined a _repr_html_ to automatically render itself. Otherwise call Styler.render to get the generated HTML.

That's why in a normal console the print only shows an object not the dataframe with colors.

You should try to use your style in a jupyter notebook.

Comment: Thank ndclt for the answer , but i am curious to know how to achieve that in Linux Console i'm not using Jupitor.