# Putting style in words of a column that are between characters in my dataframe after concatenate them

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-styles

I have the next column that came from a process of concatenating different columns.

| Name | Product | Message |
| --- | --- | --- |
| John | prod1 | Dear, &John& come and get your &prod1& for &free& |
| Mike | prod2 | Dear, &Mike& come and get your &prod2& for &free& |

So I need to export that to `Excel` and make It look like this

| Name | Product | Store | Message |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| John | prod1 | Store1 | Dear, **John** come and get your **prod1** for **free**, in your **Store1** |
| Mike | prod2 | Store2 | Dear, **Mike** come and get your **prod2** for **free**, in your **Store2** |

It´s there anyway to do this?. Or maybe when I concatenate the message to put those values in bold?

Comment: something like this 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52110530/bold-column-in-pandas-dataframe-to-html

Answer (score 0):

If you have a dataframe like:

|  | Name | Product | Store |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | John | prod1 | Store1 |
| 1 | Mike | prod2 | Store2 |

You can use:

```
df['Message'] = df.apply(lambda x: f"Dear {x.Name} come and get your {x.Product} for free at {x.Store}", axis=1)
```

to get:

|  | Name | Product | Store | Message |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | John | prod1 | Store1 | Dear John come and get your prod1 for free at Store1 |
| 1 | Mike | prod2 | Store2 | Dear Mike come and get your prod2 for free at Store2 |

If you want them in bold as well you can do so with html tags:

```
df['Message'] = df.apply(lambda x: f"Dear <b>{x.Name}</b> come and get your <b>{x.Product}</b> for free at <b>{x.Store}</b>", axis=1)
```

Now `df.style` will give you:

|  | Name | Product | Store | Message |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | John | prod1 | Store1 | Dear **John** come and get your **prod1** for free at **Store1** |
| 1 | Mike | prod2 | Store2 | Dear **Mike** come and get your **prod2** for free at **Store2** |